# VS2017 (and 2019) Community Intellisense only showing part of the Unity class/method information, missing descriptions

Tags: unity, visual-studio

If I hover keywords like `Input.GetKeyDown`, for example, I know it should tell me something about using it for autofire.

I get autocompletion and the syntax examples / override counts, all great things, but no descriptive text blurbs.

I would really like to get those descriptions turned on.

I yanked a screenshot of an old Unity forum post that has visual evidence of the problem I'm having. I know that the text blurbs exist because I've watched enough Unity videos now with VS being used and more info.

> [image: Comparison of Intellisense screenshots from old post]

This second image is a screenshot from a video.  In my editor, I do not see the line "Base class for all entities in Unity scenes." I only see the first line "class UnityEngine.GameObject"... helpful but not as helpful as it could be.  Same thing is missing in every class/method.

[image: Screenshot of Intellisense from a video]

How can I get these Intellisense description texts to show in my version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This behavior no longer happens after upgrade to 2019.1.4f1